# Часы на ПИТОН с помощью классов

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Задание звучит так, "Напишите часы на Питон с помощью классов"

в часах должны быть включены три параметра

- Часы(Integer)
- Минуты (Integer)
- Секунды (Integer)

Напишите функцию fixTime() которая  "неверное" время исправляет.
Минуты и секунды должны отображаться корректно

```
print(meine_uhr) -> "09:22:59"
meine_uhr = meine_uhr + 1
print(meine_uhr) -> "09:23:00
```

Понимаю что это довольно простая задача. Но по стечению обстоятельств, учу программирование на не родном мне языке, и не всё порой понимаю в учебном заведении. Вот пытаюсь с вами более менее усвоить эти знания. Не кидайтесь камнями. Спасибо)

Проверку на формат часов вроде криво но  написал,а как с помощью функций далее проверить формат секунд минут и часов, чтобы секунды и минуты не была более 59, а если введенные минуты больше чем 60, то автоматически добавлялись "часы" в строке "часов" ну и соответсвенно чтобы "часы" не были более 23...

```
class Uhr:
def __init__ (self, x):
    if self.checkUhrFormat == True: # and self.checkStundenFormat(Stunden) == True and self.checkMinutenFormat(Minuten) == True and self.checkSekundenFormat(Sekunden) == True:
        print("Es ist:..........Uhr" )
        # self.Stunde = Stunden
        # self.Minuten = Minuten
        # self.Sekunden = Sekunden
    else: 
        print("Die Zeitformat ist ungültig")


def checkUhrFormat(zeit):
    # uhr muss nur bis 23 sein 
    #  und von Type str sein
    if len(zeit) != 8 or type(zeit) != str: 
        return False
    if zeit[2] != ":" :
        return False
    if zeit[5] != ":" :
        return False
    else:
        return True
    
    
def checkSekundenFormat(Sekunden):
    for i in range(len(zeit)):
        if i in zeit[8] == 8:
            print("DDDDD")
```

Comment: divmod(65, 60) => (1,5)

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял, то на вход подаётся строка
что мешает

1. разбить строку через разделитель `':'`
2. перевести разделённые слова в числа
3. проверить входит ли число в диапазон 0..23 для первого числа, 0..59 для второго и третьего

ну а сами переполнения можно делать так:

```
seconds_new = seconds % 60
minutes = minutes + (seconds // 60)
minutes_new = minutes % 60
hours = hours + (minutes // 60)
hours_new = hours % 24
days = days + hours // 24
```

или так:

```
time = seconds + minutes * 60 + hours * 3600 + days * 86400

seconds = time % 60
minutes = ((time - seconds) // 60) % 60
hours = ((time - seconds - minutes * 60) // 3600) % 24
days = ((time - seconds - minutes * 60 - hours * 3600) // 86400)
```